# How can I create a mysql table named after php variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So let's say I have a variable $id and I want to create a table according to it, how can I do it?

By the way, the table will simply count something.

Please answer even if you find duplicate, as I really don't understand answers on similar questions

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: One doesn't create tables after PHP variable one does create tables after entities in the application's universe. But a PHP variable might represent such an entity too. Besides that, what do you really want to know here? How to create a table maybe? (Hint: `CREATE TABLE ...`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple find the answer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp) (edited)

```
//your connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

//query to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $id(
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
column_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)";

//execute the query
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Table $id created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: Your answer is just SQL, not PHP

Comment: @James You could do it easily. Find the answer, I have edited it. Thanks.

Comment: `Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'TABLE' `

Comment: Ohh, that's my silly mistake. Forgot the double quote. Now it must work!

Comment: Thanks it worked !

Answer (score -1):

Well, you know the variable name. `$id` for example.

So you want to issue a data definition language to MySQL saying something like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS id (
    id_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    value INT,
    whatever VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY ( id_id )
 );
```

You'll use php to create this text as a string. Then you'll issue it as a query to MySQL, and you'll have your table.  It's no big deal.

**But**: Ordinarily a table contains rows corresponding to real-world items (persons, maybe) and the table's columns describe those items (surname, given name, gender, birthdate, maybe). Creating tables named for programming-language variables is unusual. That is probably why you have not found much advice on how to do it.  With respect, if you're new to this kind of work, you probably should read a little more about table design.

Comment: "*You'll use php to create this text as a string*" what use is it without PHP code? You have just given them SQL that doesn't create the table from a variable, which is all they wanted

Comment: It's useless standing alone without php code. Intentionally so. For one thing, the questioner didn't disclose whether they use mysqli or PDO. For another thing, the questioner surely already knows how to issue a SQL query from php. If they don't know that, it's possible a little more study and design work are required before starting to hack code.

Comment: "*For one thing, the questioner didn't disclose whether they use mysqli or PDO*" So you don't have the info to answer? No need writing a generic SQL table creation when they clearly want to do it with a var ;)